# Convert Matlab HSV to OpenCV HSV

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I used Matlab tool in order to find the HSV values of a specific color in the image.

The output from the tool was:

```
% Define thresholds for channel 1 based on histogram settings
channel1Min = 0.039;
channel1Max = 0.063;

% Define thresholds for channel 2 based on histogram settings
channel2Min = 0.538;
channel2Max = 0.654;

% Define thresholds for channel 3 based on histogram settings
channel3Min = 0.102;
channel3Max = 0.247;
```

The result is exactly the color I needed.

However, im trying to implement the same color detection using OpenCV and the range of values there is very different even after transfering `BGR2RGB`.

Any idea how to use the values I got from Matlab in OpenCV?

Thank you,

Comment: In Matlab, the HSV value range is: `H: 0-1, S: 0-1, V: 0-1`, where as in OpenCV the value range is: `H: 0-180, S: 0-255, V:0-255`

Comment: Does it just mean that I need to multiply H by 180 and S,V by 255?

Comment: I would assume, yes :)